# Exception on running IE web Driver

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver

I'm new in java, using it for automatic tests. Please help me what I'm doing wrong with this code?

```
public static WebDriver driver = null;

public static WebDriver getDriver() {
if (driver == null) {

File fileIE = new File("src//test/java/iedriver.exe");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", fileIE.getAbsolutePath());
   }
try {
 driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    }
 catch (Exception e)
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Firefox or IE? What exception? I guess the `//` in your path is a mistake?

Comment: You're also missing a brace around your exception-catching code.

Comment: Firefox or IE? I'm still not clear. The tags also suggest you have question about IE.

Comment: @AndrewRegan, no. // works cool for me. A store my driver exe. locally in the project folder. Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add DesiredCapabilities to your code.

```
if (driver == null) {

    File fileIE = new File("src//test/java/iedriver.exe");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", fileIE.getAbsolutePath());                

            DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();

            try {                                       
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);                                        
            } catch (Exception e) {                 
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
       }
```

the DesiredCapabilities help to set properties for the WebDriver. A typical usecase would be to set the path for any type of the WebDriver if your local installation doesn't correspond to the default settings.

You can read about **class DesiredCapabilities** and about its' using here: [DesiredCapabilities](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/DesiredCapabilities.html)

Comment: Also change your main question' title: it should be **Exception on running of IE-driver**, instead of FF-driver.

Comment: Thank you very much man. It's started to work for me after adding your piece of code!